# bootstrap-modal dynamic content ajax in laravel

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, bootstrap-modal

I would like to load content in my bootstrap modal from ajax i can get it in an alert or console log but the part that i want to update disappears!

I tried it with $('.modal-content').html(data) but my modal-content disappears     or .append(data) but it dus not work!

I remade it really simple but it is still not working what im i dowing wrong?

THANKS for your time and help!!!

part off my main page

```
<a class="btn btn-primary"  class="quickview22" href="#" data-target="#quickviewMain55" data-categorie="1" data-trigger="hover" data-toggle="modal">Trigger modal</a>
@include('bootmodal')
```

my bootmodal view

```
<div class="modal fade in " id="quickviewMain55">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Modal ffffffffffffffftitle</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <h1>{{ $quickProducts1->first()->name }}</h1>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

this is my script

```
   jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {
   $('#quickviewMain55').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {

   var category = $(e.relatedTarget).data('categorie');

     $.ajax({

           url: 'quick-view',
           data: { category : category }, 
           success: function(data)
           {


         $('.modal-content').html(data);  


           alert(data);
           }
         });


});
});

       $.ajaxSetup({
  headers: {
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
  }
});



</script>
```

my controller

```
class QuickViewController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Request $request)
    {



         $quickProducts1 = Product::where('category_id', $request->category)->get();



         return view('bootmodal', compact('quickProducts1'))->render();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you want to append it to `.modal-content` and not `.modal-content .modal-body`?

You might want to try:
`$('.modal-content .modal-body').html(data)`

Keep us updated!

Kenny

Comment: I would personally advise `$('.modal-content .modal-body h1').append(data)`